# Is the interpreter created at the beginning and then execute the following scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a question about a shell interpreter, though I have used it for many years.

At the beginning of a shell, we always setup the environment, followed by our shells. Below are two examples:

File 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
 "bash shells"
```

File 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby 
 "ruby shells"
```

Do the above two samples mean that the interpreter of both scripts is created at the beginning and then both interpreters execute the following scripts, "Bash shells" and "Ruby shells"?

Comment: What do you mean by "bash shells" and "ruby shells"?  Why are you referring to the code in the script as a "shell"?  Are your two bash/ruby examples meant to be in the same file or in two separate files?

Comment: Of course there are in two separated files.

Comment: The sheband need not be "an interpreter". For example using `#!/bin/cat` will output the contents of the file to the terminal and using `tac` instead of `cat` will output them reversed.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with Ruby or Python, only bash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

> Under Unix-like operating systems, when a script with a **shebang** is run as a program, the program loader parses the rest of the script's initial line as an interpreter directive; the specified interpreter program is run instead, passing to it as an argument the path that was initially used when attempting to run the script. For example, if a script is named with the path `path/to/script`, and it starts with the following line:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> ```
>
> then the program loader is instructed to run the program `/bin/sh` instead (usually this is the Bourne shell or a compatible shell), passing `path/to/script` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

That line is called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line.

These two pages have more information that you will likely ever care to know about this.

http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/

http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/std/hashexclam-1.html

Comment: Ah ya, I knew Ricky Martin was singing about something computer related!